How to interface with Postfix `non_smpt_milter`?
After many hours attempting to configure OpenDKIM with Postfix and having no luck, I have come to the conclusions that:

I cannot get OpenDKIM to work
I am not able to find a suitable out-of-the box alternative to OpenDKIM

This perplexes me as, DKIM signing is crucial to email transmission, yet there doesn't seem to be any active software supporting this - please correct me if I am wrong.
So, my question now is, how do I interface with Postfix to implement my own DKIM signing.
So far, I have:

Postfix has a configuration setting non_smtp_milters which accepts a value such as inet:port. So, I now need a means to bind to this port.
I have OpenSSL installed and, using bash, I am able to implement a variety of signing algorithms, such as SHA256.

Can anyone who has experience doing something similar please provide a starting point ?
I don't mind whether:
a) a solution is provided using bash. Ideally, I would prefer this. This would likely be a means to bind to a port, and what the input/output format would need to be.
b) a solution is provided in a language such as C++. Likely to be how to bind to a port.
Any help is greatly appreciated - I have been pulling my hair out trying to get OpenDKIM to work.
Info on OpenDKIM failure
I have tried building OpenDKIM several ways. I'll list each attempt with the associated error.
Building OpenDKIM against a shared OpenSSL version
Running
./configure --disable-live-testing --prefix=/custom/opendkim --with-openssl=/custom/openssl

Returns the error
configure: error: Cannot build shared opendkim
                              against static openssl libraries.
                              Configure with --disable-shared
                              to get this working or obtain a
                              shared libssl library for
                              opendkim to use.

This happens even if I build OpenSSL with the specific flag shared.
Building a static OpenDKIM version
Next, I try to build OpenDKIM statically:
./configure --disable-live-testing --prefix=/custom/opendkim --with-openssl=/custom/openssl --disable-shared

This then returns the error:
checking for library containing ERR_peek_error... none required
checking for library containing SSL_library_init... no
checking for library containing SSL_library_init... no
configure: error: libssl not found

Building OpenSSL
./Configure --prefix=/custom/openssl '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)'

Configuring without '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)' leads to the error:
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When attempting to run /custom/openssl/bin/openssl. I have tried installing OpenDKIM also installing OpenSSL as explicitly shared with:
./Configure shared --prefix=/custom/openssl '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)'

Extra solution attempts
I have tried installing older OpenDKIM versions and the pre-release: All these reproduce the same errors as above.
I have tried setting the path variable to OpenSSL: PATH=/custom/openssl/bin:$PATH and PATH=/custom/openssl/lib64:$PATH. This does not solve the error.
I have tried altering my OpenSSL version: I built OpenSSL version 1.0.0s successfully but on inspection, it appears not to support SHA256 - I see this as too outdated so I instead try a newer version. So, I download version 1.1.1 and run:
./config --prefix=/custom/openssl '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)'

Then make and make install. Again, this gives the same error.
OS Specs
I am running Ubuntu Version 20.04.6, Focal Fossa.

Everyone is using OpenDKIM, which works perfectly fine. There are plenty of tutorials out there. Could you share what you have tried and how it failed? That's way better than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Absolutely I can - I will add an update to my question.

dkimpy works fine.

What you are trying to do? Why you want to have dkim signing in non-smtp transactions? (And the option is called non_smtpd_milters anyway, not "non_smtp_milters".) It's nothing to do with OpenDKIM, I recon. Did you set up smtp milters with smtpd_milters option?

You never do make and make install on a production server. This is not a reasonable business practice (or, better put, must be heavily reasoned, which can't be done for common software like OpenDKIM). apt install opendkim (or whatever is in your distro) is your friend, for the start. Also, I remember I've voted to close a very similar question recently, and it's from you too; this one started better, but arrived to the same place. Don't do this.
